# Lining up boundaries at corner of polygons

Tags: arcgis-pro, simplify, generalization

I have a polygon layer with the boundary of a lot of zones. The boundary of many of them skips at the intersection where multiple zones come together (shown as in the picture). I am trying to find out a way to lining them up as if the boundary is continuous.

[image]

I have tried the "Simplify Shared Edges (Cartography)" tool from the geo processing tools in ArcGIS Pro, but it only fixed those three-way intersections and not worked on four-way intersection like this. I have thousands of polygons, so it's not possible to do it all manually. I also have access to ArcMap if it is needed. I wonder if anyone have an idea about how to fix it.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Chit chat like thanks should not be included in your posts here - see [help/behavior].  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Which software are you working with? What have you tried? Which extent of map are we talking about, e.g. could you do it manually? Please edit question and tags accordingly, thank you.

Comment: Snapping occurs based on the tolerances given. But if you increase the distance, you could move the "correct" location to the "incorrect" point just as easily as the opposite. You might be able to process the image to find central locations in the white space, then snap to that, but you still need review.